# Accessing wikipedia webservices

Tags: php, web-services, wikipedia

Im searching for some Documentation on how to access the Wikipedia webservices in order to get info on some places around specific lat/long coordinates.

This is what i'm looking for:
http://www.geonames.org/export/wikipedia-webservice.html

Example call:
http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyWikipedia?lat=52.51&lng=13.44&username=demo&lang=en&maxRows=20

This is the wikipedia project website
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Geographical_coordinates

Anyone knows some php based examples on how to access the API?

Comment: Would any of these [GeoNames client libraries](http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html) help?  For example, take a look at the findNearbyWikipedia() method [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.webservices.services-geonames.getting-started.php).

Comment: Thanks. I'm searching for info on how to access wikipedia directly, without Geonames webservices.

Comment: You're not going to have much luck pulling geographical data directly from Wikipedia without _some_ middleware to extract it from the article text.

Comment: Extraction should not be the problem. I just want to know how for example i can find articles which are located in an 10 km area around some lat/long point.

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly what you can't do without either a) downloading and parsing the entire [Wikipedia database dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20111007/) or b) letting someone else do that for you.

Comment: I see. Thought wikipedia has an API for a call like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the last comment a lot of work has been invested in [Extension:GeoData](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aGeoData) which provides an API for coordinates.